# Azure service bus queue subcription filter change

Tags: .net, azure

We are planning to use azure service bus queue along with topic/subscription.

We have multiple subscriptions for a given topic with different filter conditions.

My question is can we change the filter of subscription dynamically once subscription is created? How can I change the filter condition for subscription once it is created?
I cannot find any methods which allows this? 
The only option I see is delete subscription and recreate it. 
Any idea how to change filter without deleting subscription?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use **AddRule** and **RemoveRule** on **SubscriptionClient** to modify the filters in a subscription.

Resources:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh429499.aspx)
- [Using Rule Actions in Windows Azure Service Bus Subscriptions](http://southworks.com/blog/2012/01/06/using-rule-actions-in-windows-azure-service-bus-subscriptions/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing. Jorge Rowies blog is quite useful.

Comment: In terms of behavior keep in mind that a rule is evaluated at the time when message is sent to the Topic. So while a particular rule is active its evaluated against all messages sent to the topic and when you remove the rule/create a new rule then any message sent after that rule creation will be evaluated with the new rule. All this time you may not have received/removed a single message from that subscription so these message will all be waiting and available when the receiver comes along.

Comment: Yes that's a know consequence of using AddRule/RemoveRule. How do you suggest we overcome this?

Comment: Blog entry URL http://southworks.com/blog/2012/01/06/using-rule-actions-in-windows-azure-service-bus-subscriptions/ (submitted an edit). (Reasons why it's useful to include more than the link).

Comment: Deviating from the main topic of this question, but not unrelated, under what circumstances would a subscription entail more than one rule? According to the API, I know more than one rule can be added. But I am unable to imagine why and how a subscription will be useful if it has multiple rules.

Answer (score 2):

I cant be sure it works but if anything will allow you to edit a filter it will be the Service Bus explorer from Paolo http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a

More details in this blog post on it: http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/07/exploring-topics-and-queues-by-building-a-service-bus-explorer-toolpart-1/

Can you create a new one and delete the old one, it is pub/sub after all?

HTH